# how to choose a PCB component footprint?

Tags: kicad

I am trying to create a PCB in KiCad. I was able to find the footprints needed for my THT resistors and op-amp / comparator chip. However, I am not really sure what footprint to use for my capacitors. I am new to this and don't really know the size of the capacitor (the values of the three capacitors is 22 μF, 5 nF, and 1 μF) nor where to find it. I was hoping someone could please help me figure out what footprint to use.

Comment: Are these caps THT or SMT types?  Can you add a picture of the parts being used? Note that the values of the capacitors will not determine the needed footprint.  If they are also THT have you measured the pin to pin dimensions?

Comment: You use the footprints that match your capacitors. What capacitors you have selected, or bought already?

Comment: If SMD, 0603 or 0805 are reasonable choices that are not too small to be hard to solder but not too large that they're annoying to route. If THT, use whatever you have.

Comment: Are you consulting data sheets for the dimensions and footprints? If not, do you have a pair of [calipers](https://i.imgur.com/BRhBmVi.jpg) to measure existing parts?  Even an inexpensive pair is a lot better than nothing.

Comment: If you can't easily find a suitable footprint in the libraries, you can always make your own footprint to suit the part you have.  If you do any amount of PCB layout, you WILL have to make some custom footprints.

Comment: I am using resistors from the ELEGOO super starter kit for the Arduino. However, I dont know the size of these resistors. Can someone please lead me to where I can find that information?

Answer (score 0):

> don't really know the size of the capacitor

None of us experienced folk "know" (or need to always know) in principle either, unless we use a particular set of values often. For the ever-popular switching converters, capacitors are often critical parts and need several specs to be met, not just capacitance and voltage rating. So, if it's not a generic part with "ballpark" specs, we have to look it up, each time, more or less. As experience is gained, a good designer will build up a library of parts - a combination of a schematic symbol, part data (orderable part number, stock number, etc.), and footprint.

The capacitor part sizes depend on the specifications of the part. First you choose the ratings of the capacitor based on the needs of the application. Say 100μF, 16V, ESR ≥ 0.1Ω, ripple current min. 0.8A. Then you do a parametric search for tantalum or aluminum electrolytic capacitors with those ratings on say DigiKey. Then you order them based on your design goals. Then you choose the particular part, and look at what size it has, and that's how you select the footprint to use on the board - with a particular part or family of parts or subset of orderable parts in mind.

It seems natural to think "just sort by price, ascending, choose first". If you want to avoid having to substitute parts later, popularity may be worth more than merely low price. Then you'd want to select a part with most inventory.

You may wish to avoid parts that are in stock but are end-of-life, i.e. you won't be able to buy that particular part number again later.

Or you may want to select a part with slightly better secondary ratings, like lifetime, automotive qualification, etc.

Finally you see what size the parts of your choosing are. If there are 5 popular parts with very high stock numbers, but one of them in in size B, others in size C, it may make sense to choose size C. Then, if you ever need to substitute, there'll be a higher chance of having available a part that will fit on the same footprint, without having to change board layout (however minor that change may be).

Comment: Wasn't the question about size of the component, not the value?